# In SQL Server how to get some meaningful data from a chronicle alike table?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table let's call it purchase table in SQL Server that represents user purchasing.

```
Table name: purchase
purchase_id       buyer_member_id       song_id
1                 101                   1001
2                 101                   1002
3                 102                   1001
4                 102                   1003
5                 103                   1001
6                 103                   1003
7                 103                   1004
```

Now I tried to make some stats out of this table. I want to know who has purchased both song 1001 and 1003.

```
select distinct buyer_member_id from purchase where 
buyer_member_id in (select buyer_member_id from purchase where song_id = 1001)
and buyer_member_id in (select buyer_member_id from purchase where song_id = 1003)
```

This works but when we add more and more criteria to the equation, it became slower and slower. It's nearly impossible to do a research for something like, find people who buy a, b and c but not d nor f. I understand that the nature of this and the use of "where someid in (select someid from table where something) is probably not the best way to do it.

Question is, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call these "set-within-a-set" queries, and like to approach them using `group by` and `having`:

```
select buyer_member_id
from purchase p 
group by buyer_member_id
having sum(case when song_id = 1001 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when song_id = 1003 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `sum()` counts the number of purchases that match each song.  The `> 0` says there is at least 1.  And `= 0` would say there are none.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this keyword having, Great help!